# Multipage with GnuWin32

Tags: tiff, gnuwin32

tiffSplit.exe of GnuWin32 library splits tiff images. Is it possible to convert various single page files into multipage tiff with GnuWin32 library?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `tiffcp`:

```
tiffcp -c lzw <source files> <dest file>
```

the `-c` option specifies the compression to use. If you don't use any compression then the file can be significantly larger than the input files if they are compressed.